# Formatting a text via the use of regex

Tags: regex, latex

I am not very good at regex and I would really appreciate help from experts on the fields.

I have a document as follow:

```
Text of the question 1.

A. answer A

B. answer B

C. answer C

D. answer D

E. answer E

Good answers: A, C, E

Text of the question 2.

A. ...
```

**and I would like to have it formatted as (using regex I guess):**

```
\question Text of the question 1.

\begin{itemize}

 \item answer A

 \item answer B

 \item answer C

 \item answer D

 \item answer E

\end{itemize}

\begin{solution}

Good answers: A, C, E

\end{solution}


\question Text of the question 2.

\begin{itemize}

 \item ...

\end{itemize}
```

I can do a replace of `A.` by `\begin{itemize}\n \item` and `Good answers` by `\begin{solution}\nGood answers:` but then my lack of knowledge of regex does not allow me to add the `\question`, `\end{solution}\n` tag,

Comment: language you are using along with your attempt

Comment: I added a tag Python as it is the main language I use. But I'm happy formatting the file with Word, or Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at example.

```
old_line = ""
with open("in.txt", "r") as f, open("out.txt", "w") as h:
     for ind,l in enumerate(f):
        l = l.strip()
        line = l.lower()
        if (len(line) < 2): continue
        if line.startswith("a."):  
            if(ind > 2): h.write("\\end{solution}\n")
            h.write("\question {0}\n".format(old_line))
            h.write("\\begin{itemize}\n")
        if line.startswith("good answers: "):  h.write("\\end{itemize}\n\\begin{solution}\n"+l+"\n")

        if line[0] > 'a' and line[0] <= 'z' and line[1] == '.':  h.write("\item {0}\n".format(l))
        old_line = l

     h.write("\\end{solution}\n")
```

In:

```
Text of the question 1.

A. answer A

B. answer B

C. answer C

D. answer D

E. answer E

Good answers: A, C, E
```

Out:

```
\question Text of the question 1.
\begin{itemize}
\item B. answer B
\item C. answer C
\item D. answer D
\item E. answer E
\end{itemize}
\begin{solution}
Good answers: A, C, E
\end{solution}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Indeed, I was too focused on regex that I did not even think of doing it without. Thank you very much!! Have a good day. :D